# How to safely pause Garmin navigations?

Tags: gps, garmin, performance-tracking

I need an advise how to *safely* pause a Garmin (I have Edge Explorer 2 but the problem is more general) during a longer coffee or pub (alcohol free) stop. Safely means that the screen should be locked so that no activity deletion could happen. I have had two running activities discarded already in half a year even though for the second time I knew the risk exists and I was being careful.

Why pause? Otherwise it consumes batter and sometimes creates excursions to nearby towns when inside.

What happpens now? When I press the lower right Start/Stop button. It only allows Finish or Continue, after some time it swiches to Finish itself and offers Discard or Save. If it is pressed inadvertently when carrying the touchscreen device to the bike, it will ask for confirmation, but in very confusing way. At least in the Czech localization the word that usually means Cancel actually means Discard on Garmin.

How to safely pause the device so that it can be in a pocket and the screen can be touched without any ill effects?

P.S. I know there is a way to recover a deleted file from the FAT but despite turning off the device immediately and despite the recovery software not finding any sector overwritten, the file content was just garbage.

Comment: I don't know if you have tried but the Edge Explore has a 'lock screen' functionality, judging by the manual. See page 4 (page numbering, not screen pages): https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/GUID-E67DE53E-5B08-4903-9767-F58973BC1829/EN-US/Edge_Explore_2_OM_EN-US.pdf

Comment: @DoNuT That does not pause the tracking, it is useful when it starts to rain because the water drops start to "press" the touch screen at random places.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава, that solves your problem of accidental input. Pausing tracking can be done with a hardware button press. See the answer below. Once tracking is paused *with the screen locked* you should be fine

Comment: @ArtGertner I do not see how that is connected, your answer is about something else. Or at least about much more than just the existence of the Lock button. At least the original Option A that is probably the best answer possible (given the possibilities offered by Garmin).

Comment: Or you mean keep the screed locked and *then* press Start/Stop tip pause/unpause? That would also be an option if it works. But again it is more involved than just saying that a Garmin Edge has a Lock function.

Comment: My answer (option B, based on comment by @DoNuT) explains exactly that. You turn the screen lock in advance (while riding)  then pause tracking with pause button and the screen remains locked preventing any touchscreen input. Just as you wanted.

Comment: @ArtGertner But you wrote " before you started the activity" which is something different.

Comment: As I understand the feature, you can have any way you want it. Track/Stop/Lock, Track/Lock/Stop or Lock/Track/Stop, depending on how much you want to use the touchscreen during the ride or just lock to to avoid input in your pockets. If I read the manual correctly, you have to use the button anyway and just need to make sure the device is locked in one of the possible ways. You could even do a full shutdown, I think a long-press give you the option to choose between standby and totally disabling the computer (just takes a little longer to boot and catch GPS when you continue your ride).

Comment: @DoNuT Yes, that is all very possible. But pointing out that the device has a Lock screen feature was simply not enough. And the simple existence of the button must be clear to every owner of the device. Also given that the answer that mentioned this button was already present at the time of the comment. The question was more specific.

Comment: What does 'activity deletion' mean, please?

Comment: I still think that pointing out and linking the page to the actual locking feature in the official manual isn't too bad for a start (hence, a comment), but you do you! I'm glad it works for you. ;-)

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The device records the track together with the speed, elevation and possibly heart rate, power or cadence. After the activity is finished, the record is saved and sent to Garmin Connect and after that it can be sent to other sites, such as Strava. Deletion means that the record is discarded instead of saving.

Comment: for other device recording other quantities, related to your description, can you give an update to this:
https://www.expats.cz/czech-news/article/czech-senators-say-yes-to-drinking-and-cycling ?

Comment: @EarlGrey That is not related at all. Driving any motor on non-motor vehicle in public under the influence of alcohol is prohibited.

Comment: I was just wondering about your alcohol-free remark. Even the neighbouring country Slovakia has some complex laws more in line with european standards https://ecf.com/news-and-events/news/slovakia-allows-pint-cyclists-cities-and-separate-cycle-paths

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, and doesn't that mean deletion is irrelevant to safely pausing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Option A:**

Press <kbd>start/stop</kbd> and then <kbd>power</kbd>. When activity is paused, power button will instantly switch the screen off (instead of locking the screen). This helps to further reduce battery consumption and prevents accidental touchscreen input.

When resuming the ride after your break, press the same combination of buttons in reverse. <kbd>power</kbd>, then <kbd>start/stop</kbd>. This will wake the device up and resume activity.

**Option B:**

Just ride with screen locked as suggested by @DoNuT .
To lock the screen during activity, just press <kbd>power</kbd> once. To lock the screen *before* you started the activity, press and hold <kbd>power</kbd> and tap "Lock screen". With the screen locked you will still be able to swipe right/left to move between the data screens, but won't be able to tap. This will also resolve your problem of accidental input when activity is paused.

Comment: I went for a short walk in the rain and I can confirm that all the mentioned combinations work well. What I would be the most hesitant to try is turning off the device completely, but the activity is resumed correctly after turning it back on. The sleep mode is probably enough for most situations.